# Is it possible to delete lines containing 2 differents words in Bash?

Tags: string, bash, sed

Example:

```
This house is big.
This is my house.
```

etc.

I want to remove lines which contains words: "house" AND "big". I tried using `sed` in many ways but nothing seems to be working. Any advice?

Comment: Show us some of the sed tries you did, so that one can point out what is wrong with them.

Comment: I tried 'sed' combined with 'if': when the conditions are fullfilled, then remove line, but no effects (or strange effects). I am new to Bash, I checked many topics here and on other forums and found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/house/!b;/big/d' file
```